# Not able to send email to more than 2 email address

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

models.py

```
class FollowerEmail(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    email = models.CharField('Email', max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def what(request):

    """"""
    follower = FollowerEmail.objects.filter(report=report)
    list=[]        
    for email in follower:
        list.append(email.email)
    """"""""
     if 'send_email' in request.POST:
            subject, from_email, to = 'Notification',user.email, person.parent_email
            html_content = render_to_string('report/print.html',{'person':person,
                                                                 'report':report,
                                                                 'list':list,
                                                                  }) 
            text_content = strip_tags(html_content) 
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to],bcc=[list], cc=['monKarek@live.com'])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
            msg.send()
```

The above is my view.py to send email,email is sending to "to" address properlly.Problem is with bcc tag.I am taking the email from FollowerEmail table and making a list.I am passing that list to bcc,as bcc email id list would be large,will be more than 3.

If list is having more than 2 email id,application is not sending  mail,if it is two or one,application is sending mail.What could be the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
list=[]        
for email in follower:
    list.append(email.email)
```

At this point `list` is already a Python `list` (you should probably rename this variable because this is confusing and not a good practice).

Then you use it as:

```
EmailMultiAlternatives(..., bcc=[list], ...)
```

And that is where is a typo. You are passing a list with a list item whereas you should be passing just a list of strings:

```
EmailMultiAlternatives(..., bcc=list, ...)
```